# Is it possible to export Google Apps Script Execution transcript

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a written a web Apps Script which is deployed to run in the context of user accessing the web app.

Is it possible to export web Apps Script's Execution Transcript programatically?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not directly.

You won't get a full stack trace, but you can be meticulous with Logging everything you want to be notified with. At the end of the script you could extract the log and email that.

[Logger.getLog();](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/logger?#getLog%28%29)

If you really wanted to be fancy, there are a few implementations of custom Loggers which extent the standard Logger.log(). For instance if you had an object that every time you send a log message to it, it would time-stamp overall duration, time since last log and the message passed to it, all to Logger.log. Same object could have a getLog(0 method of its own which did extra stuff - should you wish.

There is a notable logger library at [Google Apps Script Examples](https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/custom-methods/betterlog) by [Peter Herrmann](https://plus.google.com/108819361116973823673) which will also allow you to log to a spreadsheet.

But in short, no, you cannot export the execution log.

Comment: If I understand you correctly you are suggesting two options: (1) I email the logs which in turn would appear in the sent items of Gmail user accessing my App Script (2) I log all the logs to a spreadsheet and that spreadsheet would need to be shared publicly so, that user accessing the web app has rights to write into the Spreadsheet?

Comment: @Jonathon much as Romain has developed much/most of the stuff at his Google Apps Script Examples site, the BetterLog library is something I wrote and maintain there :)

Comment: is this still not possible?

Comment: Cloud logging is now available