# How can i get the Execution Transcript log data?

Tags: logging, google-apps-script

I would like to know if it's possible to get the execution transcript?

[image: execution_transcript]

Comment: There is no way to get the Execution Transcript with code.  The `Logger.getLog()` method does not get the Execution Transcript.  It gets anything produced with a `Logger.log()` statement.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to export Google Apps Script Execution transcript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18247203/is-it-possible-to-export-google-apps-script-execution-transcript)

Answer (score 0):

No, you'll have to manually copy the execution transcript.

Comment: You can actually use Logger.getLog() to get the execution transcript.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check [*Class Logger*](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/logger)

> This class allows the developer to write out text to the debugging logs.
>
> *`getLog()`*
>
> - Returns a complete list of messages in the current log. This method can be used to save or email the entire log output generated during script execution.

Here is the sample code:

```
// Generate a log, then email it to the person who ran the script.
var files = DriveApp.getFiles();
while (files.hasNext()) {
Logger.log(files.next().getName());
}
var recipient = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
var subject = 'A list of files in your Google Drive';
var body = Logger.getLog();
MailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, body);
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: The log and the execution transcript are not the same.